# jQuery slide event on .li hover?

Tags: jquery, list

My set up is a unordered list where the background of the list item is an image.  I need to slide in 3 divs (each in different ways) when a person hovers over the list item.

```
<ul id="tiles">
  <li class="hoverme" style="background: url(images/pic.jpg);">
     <div id="slide_div_1" style="display: none;">
       Lalala
     </div>
     <div id="slide_div_2" style="display: none;">
       Yayaya
     </div>
     <div id="slide_div_3" style="display: none;">
       Bababa
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can this be accomplished with jQuery?  I wasn't able to troubleshoot it anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: "each in different ways" is not very clear and can impact approach

Answer (score 0):

Following demo sets width of zero rather than `display: none` and animates the widths of child div's on a timer using jQuery. Demo would likely need modification depending on effect you are looking for

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/L2tbf/1/